# Calling a different header.php for a full-width page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently using

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) :
get_header( 'home' );
endif;
?>
```

To call 'header-home.php' on the homepage only.

I also want to call 'header-fullwidth.php' on our full width posts.

This is one of our full width posts: http://www.sickchirpse.com/photos-vatnajokull-glacier/

This is a normal post (it has a sidebar): http://www.sickchirpse.com/how-survive-european-squat-house-berlin/

What can I add to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(get_page_template() == 'your-full-width-template'):
get_header( 'full-width' );
endif;
```

You can alwasy check the current page template path with the `get_page_template()` function.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Problem is our full page post isn't a serperate template, it's still single.php but without the sidebar. Is there a way to to use the above code but change it to use the new header when a certain class has/hasn't been called? Or even when the sidebar isn't shown?

Comment: then you should use the `get_header` inside an `if` statement